# Hasse principle for $H^2$ of a maximal torus of a connected quasisplit group?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $k$ be a number field and let $G$ be a quasisplit reductive algebraic group over $k$. Does there exist a maximal torus in $G$ such that the Hasse principle in dimension $2$ holds, i.e., such that the map $H^2(k,T) \to \prod_v H^2(k_v,T)$ is injective? It is true if $G$ is split or if $G$ is adjoint. If $G$ is simply connected, it is true whether $G$ is quasisplit or not.

Comment: Just to clarify: By "Hasse principle in dimension 2" you are asking whether the map $H^2(k,T) \to \prod_v H^2(k_v,T)$ is injective for some maximal torus $T$?

Comment: Exactly .......

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  If $T$ is split, this follows from the "reciprocity" short exact sequence of Hasse (in class field theory).

Comment: No. Let $G=T$ be a $k$-torus. Then $B=T$ is a Borel subgroup defined over $k$, and hence $G$ is a quasi-split reductive $k$-group. The only maximal torus in $G$ is $T=G$. I think that there exist a $k$-torus for which the Hasse principle for $H^2$ fails.

Comment: Now I see that you already had the split case.  By restriction and corestriction, the kernel of your map is contained in the $N$-torsion, where $N$ is the greatest common divisor of all degrees of all finite extension fields that split $T$.

Comment: **Yes**, if $G$ is semisimple, not necessarily quasisplit. Indeed, let $v$ be a nonarachimedean place of $k$. Then there exists an anisotropic maximal $k_v$-torus $T_v\subset G_{k_v}$; see Platonov and Rapinchuk, Section 6.5, Theorem 21 of the Russian edition. There exist a maximal $k$-torus $T\subset G$ that is conjugate to $T_v$ over $k_v$. Thus $T_{k_v}$ is anisotropic. It follows that $Ш^2(k,T)=1$; see  formula (1.9.3) in Sansuc's paper:  Sansuc, J.-J. Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres. J. Reine Angew. Math. 327 (1981), 12–80.

Comment: Theorem 21 in Section 6.5 of the Russian edition of Platonov and Rapinchuk is Theorem 6.21 of the English edition.